# How to enable the Webform module?

Tags: 8, webforms

[image]

The tick box is greyed out. What is the "Contribute" module and where can I find it?

Comment: Add  and enable Contibute module( https://www.drupal.org/project/contribute).Try with drush  it will automatically install the required modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can found it at https://www.drupal.org/project/contribute

> The Contribute module adds a 'Community information' section to
>   Drupal's status report (/admin/reports/status) which encourages
>   individuals and organizations to join the Drupal community, become
>   members of the Drupal Association, and contribute to Drupal projects,
>   events, and more.

Maybe you should read this article: [The Webform module now depends on the Contribute module](https://www.jrockowitz.com/blog/contribute)

Comment: IMO the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module should start "depending" on that module ASAP also ...

Comment: There is also a minor bug (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2941297) that we just resolved and we will be tagging a hotfix release in the next day or so.